# Replace pattern in file with pattern in second file

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed, awk

I want to replace part of a file's data, with data from another file.

Suppose `file1` has data as is written below and `file2` has some data I want to store and replace `file1` data from `file2` from starting pattern: `// +++ CUSTOMIZATION SETTINGS START +++` and the end pattern: `// +++ CUSTOMIZATION SETTINGS END +++`.

In `file1`:

```
ANJALI
NISHA

// +++ CUSTOMIZATION SETTINGS START +++ 

WE WILL BE ON LEAVE FOR TODAY 

// +++ CUSTOMIZATION SETTINGS END +++ 

PREETI
MONA
```

In `file2`:

```
MANISH
MADHVI

// +++ CUSTOMIZATION SETTINGS START +++ 

WELCOME  ALL 

// +++ CUSTOMIZATION SETTINGS END +++ 

NISHA
TUSHAR
```

In `file3` as output:

```
ANJALI
NISHA

// +++ CUSTOMIZATION SETTINGS START +++ 

WELCOME  ALL 

// +++ CUSTOMIZATION SETTINGS END +++ 

PREETI
MONA
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ awk '/SETTINGS START/,/SETTINGS END/ {if (FNR==NR) {a=a"\n"$0}} FNR==NR{next}   /SETTINGS START/{print substr(a,2)} /SETTINGS START/,/CUSTOMIZATION SETTINGS END/{next}  1' file2 file1
ANJALI NISHA

// +++ CUSTOMIZATION SETTINGS START +++

WELCOME ALL

// +++ CUSTOMIZATION SETTINGS END +++

PREETI MONA
```

#### Explanation

`awk` implicitly loops through files line by line.  In this case, we have it loop through file2 first, then file1.

- `/SETTINGS START/,/SETTINGS END/ {if (FNR==NR) {a=a"\n"$0}}`

  The settings section from file2 is captured in the variable `a`.
- `FNR==NR{next}`

  If we are still reading file2, skip the rest of the commands and jump to the next line of input.
- `/SETTINGS START/{print substr(a,2)}`

  If we get here, we are processing file1.  When we see the start of the settings section, print the string that we have saved in the variable `a`.
- `/SETTINGS START/,/CUSTOMIZATION SETTINGS END/{next}`

  If we are in the settings section of file1, skip the rest of the commands and go to the next input line.
- `1`

  `1` is awk's cryptic shorthand for print the current line.  We only get to this statement if we are in file1 but not in the settings section.